# Listing content inside an OG based on a tag name provided in the URL

Tags: panels, views, chaos-tool-suite

I have a site divided in 4 organic groups:

- Product
- Corporate
- Data
- Users

Users belonging to a group are able to post content in that group as well as read it. Every group has its page accessible through the following URLs

- example.com/product
- example.com/corporate
- example.com/data
- example.com/users

in which an overview of the latest content published in  that group is shown inside a set of panels.

Every group has an specific vocabulary of 4 terms in order to subdivide content classification a little bit more.

THE GOAL IS:

I want to build some pages with page manager so that when a visitor types an URL like example.com/product/foo a page with the same design as the others is shown but filtering the contents inside that group to those tagged as "foo".

To achieve this I've started creating a page variant that would deal with requests in the form /product/%tag with the condition that %tag is a term in the "product" group vocabulary.

Up to this point, this works. When a user browses to example.com/product/foo the page shows as it should, and when it browses to example.com/product/bar (bar is not in the vocabulary) a "page not found" message is displayed.

Inside the views manager I also created a content pane view with the contextual filter based on term ID that:

- When the filter is not available displays all results.
- When the filter is available

  - Specify validation criteria
  - Validator: Taxonomy term
  - Vocabularies: corporate, data, product, users
  - Filter value type: Term name converted to term ID
  - Transform dashes in URL to spaces...
  - Action to take if filter doe not validate: Display content of "no result found"

THE PROBLEM:

The preview works well in the view admin page when providing the contextual filters but when I try it on the actual page, the "no results" found content is show.

Is there something I have to do with the "Argument input" option inside the views admin page? Am I trying to solve this issue twice by using page manager and contextual filters (should I use only one approach)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answer to my question is that when the filter is not available, I should provide a default value -> raw value from URL -> path component = 2

And check "use path alias" option to avoid using regular paths.

And also argument input = from panel argument (first).